# dropdown in primefaces datatable livescroll

Tags: drop-down-menu, primefaces, datatable

I am using datatable of primefaces and using its feature of livescroll. But i am facing a strange issue. When i scroll down, data gets loaded on the screen in a perfect manner except dropdowns (using p:selectOneMMeny) for this. Is there some issue with drop down and live scroll. Please help. PFB my code.. for the same..

```
<p:dataTable id="searchTable" var="student" value="#{dataBean.students}"
   scrollRows="10" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200" liveScroll="true" >

   <p:column styleClass="colum8" style="text-align: center; background-color:#dcdcdc; width: 150px;padding: 4px;">
        <f:facet name="header">
                 <h:outputText value="#{msgs.mpromo_buscar_estatus}" />
        </f:facet>  

        <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="DropDownBuscarStyle" id="promoEstatusDD" value="#{promo.estatusID}" valueChangeListener="#{buscarMB.estatusChangeListener}" disabled="#{sessionScope['UserDetails'].perfil ne 'MKT'}"  onchange="setSpanValueOfDropDown(this);">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs.mpromo_buscar_select}" itemValue="-1"></f:selectItem>
    <f:selectItems value="#{buscarMB.estatusSelectList}" />                 <p:ajax event="change"  listener="#{buscarMB.changeStatus}" oncomplete="changeStatusComplete();" update="@this :buscarForm:isEstatusChangeDeniedId :buscarForm:divError editLinkId">                            </p:ajax>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    </p:datatable>
```